# WebSocket data cannot be converted to array from the buffer

Tags: javascript, websocket, buffer

I simply send an array from client to server. When I try to log this array from the client-side it gives me random values in the array.

**Client-Side Code**

```js
let ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:4000");
ws.send([1,2,3]);
```

**Server-Side Code**

```js
wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
  ws.on("message", m => {
    //I searched a little and learnt a way to convert buffer to array with a simple ES6 feature but it doesn't work properly
    console.log([...m]);
  });
});
```

The output is: `[ 49, 44, 50, 44, 51 ]`

Please post how can I fix it, and explain the reason for it so I and other people can understand the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

try parsing the buffer into a javascript object using `JSON.parse(m)`is not required.
Please note that if the message is not a JSON string, this will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why it happens but know I got a workaround for this problem. I'm simply converting the array to a string on the client-side and reconverting it to an array on the server side.

Client-Side

```js
ws.send([1,2,3].toString());
```

Server Side

```js
arr = []

wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
    ws.on("message", m => {
        arr = m.toString().split(",");
        arr = arr.map(x => {
            return parseInt(x);
        });
        console.log(arr);
    });
});
```